# Intel HDA connector - jack detection

Tags: audio, intel

Good morning/afternoon/evening

I'm trying to resolve an issue related to Jack autodetection on an Intel motherboard

In a nutshell, I'm using a home made simple adapter for the HDA connector on the motherboard, to connect the line output of this HDA connector to an amplifier. There is a simple loopback wire between ground and the sense input.

Issue I'm running into is that the SW does detect there's something connected, but considers it's a headphone and not a speaker (and this is causing all sort of other issues in my use case).

I've been trying to find information on how this would work, apparently some impedance measurement at start, but I'm unclear on what would be considered as a valid value for the system to recognize a speaker instead of a headphone

If anyone would have a pointer, that would be welcome

Regards

Comment: What on earth is an intel HDA connector?

Answer (score 0):

Bad news for you: according to official HDA spec, [Front Panel I/O Connectivity Design Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20110511144045if_/http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/A2928604-005.pdf), the dongle does not decide the device type. Page 25 shows dongle schematics, and the only resistor there is 1K "PRESENSE#" resistor to tell MB that this dongle supports HDA. The "SENSE_SEND" wires are connected to plain switches, and then to SENSE_RETURN.

Now, according to page 24 of the same doc, there are "Rjd_port" resistors right on the motherboard in series with SENSE_RETURN lines which set the port type. You can maybe modify them if you add parallel/series resisitors yourself into the dongle, but this is unsupported, and you will have to figure out what resistors does your motherboard have first. Section 7.4.2 / pg 222 of [High Definition Audio Specification](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-specifications/high-definition-audio-specification.pdf) may be helpful here -- it mentions resistances of 5.1K, 10K, 20K, 39.2K.

But the important thing is that from the HDA standpoint, all those sense circuits just activate various bits in the codec status, and it is up to the driver how to interpret them. I think the software solution might be the easiest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure out how to proceed based on these specifications how to proceed